# Android Thread.MIN_PRIORITY

Tags: android, thread-priority

I have some logic in my android app to set all the threads's priority in a thread pool to be Thread.MIN_PRIORITY (which has an integer value 1 according to http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html).

But when i did a

```
adb shell ps -t -p
```

It gave me this:

```
thread_4     15581 15060 628480 139992 39    19    0     0     c00d12b0 40106600 S Downloader #1
```

Where 39 should be the thread's priority.

I'm baffled that how Thread.MIN_PRIORITY gets translated into 39?

Comment: I doubt that they're altering priority directly at all-  they're almost certainly setting the nice value with that, which is the next column over.  Lower nice is higher priority, and its on a scale of (-20, 19).  The other priority is calculated by the OS (linux, not android here) and will be changed based on program behavior like IO usage and how long its been blocked.

Comment: In addition to Gabe's comment, you can use [Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_LOWEST)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html) set the system pthread priority, AKA. the nice column in the ps command output (19 is the lowest value).